# .NET Standard and Blank XAML App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I am trying to get my Xamarin App upgraded to target .NET Standard. After breaking my solution numerous times I have now tried to do this from a blank application.

First, I have everything as up to date as possible, including Xamarin, Visual Studio, .Net Core, Android SDK and Windows 10 (Anni update + all patches).

If I create a Blank XAML App (Xamarin.Forms.Portable), the process works fine and I get a Droid, IOS, UWP and two Win8.x projects. Everything builds and runs fine in emulators and devices.

I then delete the two Win8 projects to leave just the PCL, IOS, Droid and UWP.

From here I try change the target on the PCL. On the portable app - click properties - click Target .NET Platform Standard. I click Yes to confirm and get the Nuget 3.0 error.

[image: Nuget 3.0 issue]

I remove the reference to Xamarin.Forms and change the target again and get a host of errors (quoted below).

Am I missing something or is it just not possible to run .NET Standard and Blank XAML App (Xamarin.Forms.Portable) projects?

> Code  Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Build action
>   'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's
>   targets.  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml  0       Build action
>   'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's
>   targets.  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\MainPage.xaml 0       Package restore
>   failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App4'.          0       The
>   "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'App4,
>   Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist
>   in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'App4.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String
>   fileName)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1
>   jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1
>   resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() App4.Droid
>   CS0103    The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current
>   context   App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   14  Active
>   CS0115    'App.OnResume()': no suitable method found to
>   override  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   29  Active
>   CS0115    'App.OnSleep()': no suitable method found to
>   override  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   24  Active
>   CS0115    'App.OnStart()': no suitable method found to
>   override  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   19  Active
>   CS0118    'MainPage' is a type but is used like a
>   variable  App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   16  Active CS0246   The
>   type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   10  Active
>   CS0246    The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   App4    C:\Dev\App4\App4\App4\App.xaml.cs   6   Active
>   IDE0006   Error encountered while loading the project. Some project
>   features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and
>   projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   App4.Droid      1   Active

I also tried to create a Blank XAML App (Xamarin.Forms.Portable) and then upgrade the Xamarin nuget packages (without targeting Standard) and this also fails (upgrading Xamarin.Forms from 2.2.0.45 to 2.3.2.127) with:

> Code  Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail
>   Description IDE0006   Error encountered while loading the project. Some
>   project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed
>   project and projects that depend on it, have been
>   disabled. App5.Droid      1   Active  To see what caused the issue, please
>   try below.
>
> 1. Close Visual Studio
> 2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt
> 3. Set environment variable “TraceDesignTime” to true (set TraceDesignTime=true)
> 4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file
> 5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment varaible (devenv)
> 6. Open the solution
> 7. Check 'C:\Users\m_f\AppData\Local\Temp\App5.Droid_*.designtime.log' and
>      look for the failed tasks (FAILED)

I am just trying to keep my solution up to date and keep up with the constant changes, but it looks like (for now) I am stuck on an older version that cannot be upgraded?

Frustrating!

Comment: Do you have updated Xamarin to fastest beer?

Comment: I like fast beer?

Comment: I'm sorry, my meaning is that do you have updated Xamarin to lastest version?

Comment: Yes. All up to date.

Comment: have you tried removing **all** references before removing projects from PCL?